# Google Spreadsheet; function to automatically remove PART of text on automated cell entry

Tags: excel

I have a program that inputs the full date as this:

```
Wed Aug 10 03:20:50 +0000 2016
```

However, I need to remove the last 11 digits (**+0000 2016**) from the sequence for the rest of my formulas to work.

Is there a way to write this in so it will continually do this on that cell as it auto-populates?

Comment: You might want to share the code (or sufficient snippets of it) you've already worked out.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to show the midrange, minus the last 11 characters.  The formula looks like this:

```
=MID(B5,1,LEN(B5)-11)
```

That is, the characters from 1 to the full length, minus 11.
Keep in mind, though...  If the value of the cell is update live, you're going to have a different formula in it.  You should probably run the LIVE portion of it in one cell, and have THIS cell be the one you run the rest of your stuff on.

Comment: Brilliant. Worked perfectly. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Eggsellent!  Glad to hear it worked.  Please accept the answer.